# How could I prevent a user from querying SELECT on other schemas in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, privileges, sql-grant

I'm using Oracle 11g(11.2.0.1.0). I created about 20 tablespaces and users. And the data came by [Tools] - [Database Copy] on Oracle SQL Developer.

Somehow I found that a user is using `SELECT` query on the table from another schema. I want to prevent it for security. How should I change my grant options?

I read "Oracle Database Security Guide 11g Release 2(11.2)", but couldn't find the solution clearly.

Here are my creating and granting queries.

```sql
create user [USER_NAME]
identified by [PASSWORD]
default tablespace [TABLESPACE_NAME]
temporary tablespace TEMP;

grant create session,
      create database link,
      create materialized view,
      create procedure,
      create public synonym,
      create role,
      create sequence,
      create synonym,
      create table,
      drop any table,
      create trigger,
      create type,
      create view to [USER_NAME];

alter user [USER_NAME] quota unlimited on [TABLESPACE_NAME];
```

And here is the `SELECT` result of session_privs on a user.

```sql
SQL> SELECT * FROM session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
CREATE TABLE
DROP ANY TABLE
CREATE SYNONYM
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM
CREATE VIEW
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE DATABASE LINK
CREATE ROLE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER

PRIVILEGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE TYPE

13 rows selected.
```

I want to prevent a user from querying `SELECT` on other schemas.

For example, the following query

```sql
-- connected with USER1
SELECT *
  FROM USER2.table1;
```

should make an error like:

```
ERROR: USER1 doesn't have SELECT privilege on USER2.
```

---

Edited:

- Use appropriate terms (changed some words from `tablespace` to `schema`)
- Add `SELECT` result of session_privs on a user
- Add the method of how the data came by.

Comment: You reference tables in a schema (user), not tablespace. Have you given the tablespaces the same names as the schemas, perhaps? And you grant select privileges on tables not tablespaces. If one user can see another user's data then they have been granted select privs on that table. Or you've given them powerful `select any` privs, which you haven't shown. (Why have you given them `drop any table`? That sounds dangerous...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you. I have just learned the difference among a `user`, a `schema`, and a `tablespace`. I used the same name for a user and a tablespace. But I didn't grant any privileges not listed in my question. (I will revoke `drop any table`... Thank you for detail help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. I missed that I had added some **role**s.

To copy data using Oracle SQL Developer, I added predefined roles to users. The roles were `exp_full_database` and `imp_full_database`.

According to [Oracle Database Security Guide: Configuring Privilege and Role Authorization](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#DBSEG004), `exp_full_database` contains these privileges:

- `SELECT ANY TABLE`
- `BACKUP ANY TABLE`
- `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE`
- `EXECUTE ANY TYPE`
- `ADMINISTER RESOURCE MANAGER`
- `INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON SYS.INCVID, SYS.INCFIL AND SYS.INCEXP`

and roles:

- `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE`
- `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`

Those roles are not required now. So the answer is removing them from users.

```sql
REVOKE exp_full_database, imp_full_databsae FROM USER1;
```

And I get the result I wanted.

```sql
-- connected with USER1
SELECT * FROM USER2.TABLE1;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```